# Post 3 level complex C# object to posstasjsonaynch

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have to call an api which needs 3 level json request.

```
class foo { public List<StudentList> students { get; set; } }

class StudentList 
{
     public string studentid { get; set; } 

     public string researchId { get; set; } 

     public List<courses> courseList { get; set; }
     public List<examsschedule> exams { get; set }
}

class courses { 
    public string courseId { get; set; } 
    public string courseName { get; set; }
    public string professsorName { get; set; }
}

class exams 
{
    /****/ 
}
```

I have to post this as json to api. postasjsonasynch

When I send object of "foo" class, api rejects as it is not as json format.

```
var payload = fooObject 

/*object of foo*/ 
var httpContent = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
```

I'm using web api's postasjsonaynch

[jsonproperty] is this used only for capturing response or also building request ?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution,

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            var url = "http://localhost:64743/";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

             //Post    
              var students = new List<StudentList>
              {
                 new StudentList { researchid="1234", studentid="5689",
                  courses = new List<Course>
                    {
                    new Course { courseName="os", professorName="donchi lee"           },
                      new Course { courseName="database", professorName="jie,joe" }
                           },
                                      exams=new List<Exam> { }
                                 }
                                };

                           var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Student", students).ConfigureAwait(false).Result;
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                              {
                               Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                                   }
                                      }
```